# Recursive Paired List Search in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a function that recursively searches a list of key - value pairs for a given key, and returns the value. If the list doesn't contain the given key, it is to return a given integer value 'def'. I haven't added the second part yet, but the beginning of my function is throwing a parse error, and I'm not sure why. Also any tips as to how to implement the second part of the function would be much appreciated!
Here's my function:

```
assoc :: Int -> String -> [(String, Int)] -> Int
assoc def key ((k,v) : ps)
  | key == k = v
  | otherwise assoc def key ps
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an `=` after your `otherwise`.

As for the second part, you will need a base case to handle the empty list.

Comment: What would that look like, something like `assoc _[] = def`   ?

Comment: That can't be right, because your function has three arguments, not two. But you're close.

Answer (score 1):

One way to construct this function using the standard library is via [`Data.List.lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup). Since what your function does is perform a lookup, but provide a default if not found, I might call it `lookupWithDefault`:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

lookupWithDefault :: Eq a => b -> a -> [(a, b)] -> b
lookupWithDefault def key pairs = fromMaybe def (lookup key pairs)
```

If, however, you're practicing recursive functions, the missing base case that amalloy speaks of is:

```
assoc :: Int -> String -> [(String, Int)] -> Int
assoc def _key [] = undefined -- here
assoc def key ((k,v) : ps)
  | key == k = v
  | otherwise = assoc def key ps
```